# Program Error-graphic window not showing when program is run

Tags: python, graphics

I'm working on creating a "three door monte" program using the graphic.py library, but I cant figure out what I've done wrong that is causing the graphic window not to load. Any suggestions or tips? Knowing my luck, my mistake is a basic one

```
from random import randrange
from graphics import *


class Door:

    def __init__(self,win,center,width,height,label):

        #mark secret door
        # 0 = not this door
        # 1 = this is scret door
        self.secret = 0

        self.hasClick = 0

        #get X,Y from center and find border of the door
        x,y = center.getX(),center.getY()
        self.xmin, self.xmax = x-width/2,x+width/2
        self.ymin, self.ymax = y-height/2,y+height/2

        #draw a door border
        self.rec = Rectangle(Point(self.xmin,self.ymax),Point(self.xmax,self.ymin))
        self.rec.setFill(color_rgb(250,216,21))
        self.rec.setWidth(0)
        self.rec.draw(win)


        #draw doorknob
        self.knob = Circle(Point(x+(width/3.2),y),width/12)
        self.knob.setFill(color_rgb(255,255,0))
        self.knob.setWidth(0)
        self.knob.draw(win)


        #draw label
        self.label= Rectangle(Point(x-(width/2.8),y+(height/2.4)),Point(x+(width/3),y++(height/3.5)))
        self.label.setFill(color_rgb(227,219,178))
        self.label.setWidth(0)
        self.label.draw(win)

        #draw text on label
        self.text = Text(Point(x,y+(height/2.8)),label)
        self.text.setSize(10)
        self.text.draw(win)


    def setSecret(self):
        #set door as the secret door
        self.secret = 1
        print()


    def turnGreen(self):
       #Turn door color green to present this is a correct door.
        self.rec.setFill(color_rgb(79,232,17))
        self.knob.setFill(color_rgb(51,176,0))
        self.label1.setFill(color_rgb(51,176,0))


    def turnRed(self):
        #Turn door red if user click on wrong door.
        self.rec.setFill(color_rgb(241,41,41))
        self.knob.setFill(color_rgb(254,40,56))
        self.label.setFill(color_rgb(254,40,56))


    def clicked(self,c):
        if self.xmin <= c.getX() <= self.xmax and self.ymin <= c.getY() <= self.ymax:
            self.hasClick = 1

        return (self.xmin <= c.getX() <= self.xmax and
                self.ymin <= c.getY() <= self.ymax)


    def reveal(self):

        #if user click on a correct door
        if self.secret == 1 and self.hasClick == 1:
            self.turnGreen()
            return 'win'

        #if user click on wrong door turn it to red
        elif self.secret == 0 and self.hasClick == 1:
            self.turnRed()

        #reveal secret door if necessary 
        elif self.secret ==1 and self.hasClick ==0:
            self.turnGreen()
            return 'secret'



def main():

    win,msg,d1,d2,d3 = drawGUI()
    secretDoor(d1,d2,d3)
    getInput(win,d1,d2,d3)
    result(msg,d1,d2,d3)
    exit(win)



def drawGUI():


    #setup windows
    win = GraphWin('Three Door Monte',390,300)
    win.setCoords(0,0,130,100)
    win.setBackground('white')

    #draw doors
    d1 = Door(win,Point(25,60),30,53,'Door 1')
    d2 = Door(win,Point(65,60),30,53,'Door 2')
    d3 = Door(win,Point(105,60),30,53,'Door 3')

    #create title of program
    title = Text(Point(65,95),'Three Door Monte')
    title.setSize(17)
    title.draw(win)

    #draw box to display messages
    msgBox = Rectangle(Point(10,25),Point(120,9))
    msgBox.setFill('yellow3')
    msgBox.setWidth(0)
    msgBox.draw(win)

    #draw message to invite user
    msg = Text(Point(65,17),'Guess which is the winning door')
    msg.setSize(13)
    msg.draw(win)

    return win,msg,d1,d2,d3



def secretDoor(d1,d2,d3):

    i = randrange(1,4)

    if i == 1: d1.setSecret()
    elif i == 2 : d2.setSecret()
    else: d3.setSecret()


def getInput(win,d1,d2,d3):
   #wait for user to select a door

    p = win.getMouse()

    while not d1.clicked(p) and not d2.clicked(p) and not d3.clicked(p):
        p = win.getMouse()       



def result(msg,d1,d2,d3):
 #display the results

    #door reveals whether green or blue
    x = d1.reveal()
    y = d2.reveal()
    z = d3.reveal()

    #display winning message
    if x == 'win' or y == 'win' or z == 'win':
        msg.setText('You win!\nClick anywhere to close!')

   #if user did not pick the winning door
    else:
        if x == 'secret': wayout = '1'
        elif y == 'secret': wayout = '2'
        else: wayout = '3'

        msg.setText('You lose!!\
        \nClick anywhere to close!'.format(wayout))


def exit(win):
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()
```

Comment: is it possible you just forgot to call `main()`?

Comment: is this the whole script? you don't have any code that calls it.

Comment: *facepalm* well now I feel like an idiot. Thank you. Sorry, I'm still new to the language, and tend to make petty mistakes

Comment: No problem at all, I'm labeling this as a duplicate of [Python's Equivalent of "public static void main"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907637/pythons-equivalent-of-public-static-void-main) because there are some answers there that describe good form for dealing with a main, and being labeled a duplicate will help tell other users that this question is resolved.